# Not able to retrieve individual post meta values in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, post, meta

I'm very new to post meta values and implementing them into Wordpress themes.  Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is list individual post meta values on specific parts of a single post.  But I'm having no progress because of the fact that nothing I try seems to work.  If, for example, I want to display the meta value for a key called `Model`, none of these work:

```
<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Model', true);  ?>
<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Model', false);  ?>
<?php get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'Model', true);  ?>
```

Not even this works--and it should:

```
<?php get_post_meta( get_the_id() );  ?>
```

The only thing that has worked so far for listing meta values is this:
    `<?php the_meta(); ?>`
But of course, it's no good to me because it lists *all* of my meta values for that post, and I need to be able to separately import *individual* meta values.

I know for a fact that I'm in the loop when I'm calling these functions, and I know for a fact that `get_post_id()` works because I did an `echo` with it.  The only thing I can think is that I'm declaring the string for the `$key` improperly, or declaring the boolean value for `$single` improperly, and Wordpress documentation is very spotty for both of those.  But then, neither `$key` nor `$single` was a factor in that fourth code example I listed above.  So really, I'm stuck.

Can someone help me out please?

(P.S. I'm trying this meta thing with the default Twenty Eleven and Twenty Twelve themes, so the themes themselves shouldn't be the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_post_meta() returns a value, while the_meta() echoes all the metas, they're not equivalent. Have you tried this?

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'Model',true); ?>
```

Comment: Duh!  "Echo" is basic PHP; I should have known that!  Still, this is why Wordpress needs better documentation.  To answer your question, it worked like a charm!  Thanks, mate!  I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me, haha

Comment: it is in the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)